# How make this relation in stack MERN?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mern

I have Online Shop, where exists products and category. The product has in model field

```
 category: {
    type: Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Category",
    required: [true, "Product category is required"]
  },
```

and when i add new product select category ( in list exists ) and add id.

But if remove category, the products have categoryId which does not exists. Is it possible to implement the functionality that used in wordpress. For example if in wordpress i remove category, all posts who had this category, transfer in category uncategorized (This category create automatically and cannot be delete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can use [mongoose middlewares](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html) to "cascade deleting". So when a category is removed, you can to code that every product has now "Uncategorized"

You can use a `pre` hook when you call delete function and do something like this (not tested with your schema):

```js
category.pre(/(?:delete|remove)/, function(next) {
    var id = this.getQuery()._id; //get category _id
    product.updateMany({
      category: id
    },{
      $set:{
        category:yourUncategorizedId
      }
    }).then(next()).catch(e => next(e))
})
```

So, in this case, a `regex` match is used to go into the hook.

This hook is called when a `remove` or `delete` function is called from `category` model. So, when a category is deleted, this hook will update all references by your `uncategorizedId` to ensure any product has a non-existing `category` reference.